# Kube-Prometheus-Stack Helm Chart v14.40 : Node-exporter and scrape targets unhealthy in Docker For Mac Kubernetes Cluster on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I have installed kube-prometheus-stack as a **dependency** in my helm chart on a local Docker for Mac Kubernetes cluster v1.19.7.

The **myrelease-name-prometheus-node-exporter** service is failing with errors received from the node-exporter daemonset after installation of the helm chart for [kube-prometheus-stack](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack#!) is installed. This is installed in a Docker Desktop for Mac Kubernetes Cluster environment.

**release-name-prometheus-node-exporter daemonset error log**

```sh
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-token-zft28" : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Error: failed to start container "node-exporter": Error response from daemon: path / is mounted on / but it is not a shared or slave mount
Back-off restarting failed container
```

The scrape targets for `kube-scheduler:http://192.168.65.4:10251/metrics`, `kube-proxy:http://192.168.65.4:10249/metrics`, `kube-etcd:http://192.168.65.4:2379/metrics`, `kube-controller-manager:http://192.168.65.4:10252/metrics` and `node-exporter:http://192.168.65.4:9100/metrics` are marked as unhealthy. All show as `connection refused`, except for `kube-etcd` which displays `connection reset by peer`.

**Chart.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: "0.0.1"
description: A Helm chart for flaskapi deployment
name: flaskapi
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
- name: kube-prometheus-stack
  version: "14.4.0"
  repository: "https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts"
- name: ingress-nginx
  version: "3.25.0"
  repository: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
- name: redis
  version: "12.9.0"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

**Values.yaml**

```yaml
hostname: flaskapi-service
redis_host: flaskapi-redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local 
redis_port: "6379"
```

**Environment**
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7
Docker Desktop For Mac 3.2.2(61853) with docker engine v20.10.5
Local Kubernetes 1.19.7 Cluster provided by Docker Desktop For Mac

- Prometheus Operator version:

  [kube-prometheus-stack](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack#!) 14.4.0
- Kubernetes version information:

  `kubectl version`

```sh
    Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:23:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:15:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**kubectl get all**

```sh
NAME                                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/alertmanager-flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running            0          16m
pod/flask-deployment-775fcf8ff-2hp9s                         1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flask-deployment-775fcf8ff-4qdjn                         1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flask-deployment-775fcf8ff-6bvmv                         1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-grafana-6cb58f6656-77rqk                        2/2     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-ingress-nginx-controller-ccfc7b6df-qvl7d        1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-operator-69f4bcf865-tq4q2     1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-kube-state-metrics-67c7f5f854-hbr27             1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-7hgnm                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          16m
pod/flaskapi-redis-master-0                                  1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-redis-slave-0                                   1/1     Running            0          16m
pod/flaskapi-redis-slave-1                                   1/1     Running            0          15m
pod/prometheus-flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-prometheus-0       2/2     Running            0          16m

NAME                                                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/alertmanager-operated                         ClusterIP      None             <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   16m
service/flask-api-service                             ClusterIP      10.108.242.86    <none>        4444/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-grafana                              ClusterIP      10.98.186.112    <none>        80/TCP                       16m
service/flaskapi-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.102.217.51    localhost     80:30347/TCP,443:31422/TCP   16m
service/flaskapi-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.99.21.136     <none>        443/TCP                      16m
service/flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-alertmanager       ClusterIP      10.107.215.73    <none>        9093/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-operator           ClusterIP      10.107.162.227   <none>        443/TCP                      16m
service/flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-prometheus         ClusterIP      10.96.168.75     <none>        9090/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-kube-state-metrics                   ClusterIP      10.100.118.21    <none>        8080/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter             ClusterIP      10.97.61.162     <none>        9100/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-redis-headless                       ClusterIP      None             <none>        6379/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-redis-master                         ClusterIP      10.96.192.160    <none>        6379/TCP                     16m
service/flaskapi-redis-slave                          ClusterIP      10.107.119.108   <none>        6379/TCP                     16m
service/kubernetes                                    ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      5d1h
service/prometheus-operated                           ClusterIP      None             <none>        9090/TCP                     16m

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter   1         1         0       1            0           <none>          16m

NAME                                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/flask-deployment                      3/3     3            3           16m
deployment.apps/flaskapi-grafana                      1/1     1            1           16m
deployment.apps/flaskapi-ingress-nginx-controller     1/1     1            1           16m
deployment.apps/flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-operator   1/1     1            1           16m
deployment.apps/flaskapi-kube-state-metrics           1/1     1            1           16m

NAME                                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/flask-deployment-775fcf8ff                       3         3         3       16m
replicaset.apps/flaskapi-grafana-6cb58f6656                      1         1         1       16m
replicaset.apps/flaskapi-ingress-nginx-controller-ccfc7b6df      1         1         1       16m
replicaset.apps/flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-operator-69f4bcf865   1         1         1       16m
replicaset.apps/flaskapi-kube-state-metrics-67c7f5f854           1         1         1       16m

NAME                                                                    READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/alertmanager-flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-alertmanager   1/1     16m
statefulset.apps/flaskapi-redis-master                                  1/1     16m
statefulset.apps/flaskapi-redis-slave                                   2/2     16m
statefulset.apps/prometheus-flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-prometheus       1/1     16m
```

**kubectl get svc -n kube-system**

```sh
flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-coredns                   ClusterIP   None         <none>        9153/TCP                       29s
flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-kube-controller-manager   ClusterIP   None         <none>        10252/TCP                      29s
flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-kube-etcd                 ClusterIP   None         <none>        2379/TCP                       29s
flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-kube-proxy                ClusterIP   None         <none>        10249/TCP                      29s
flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-kube-scheduler            ClusterIP   None         <none>        10251/TCP                      29s
flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-kubelet                   ClusterIP   None         <none>        10250/TCP,10255/TCP,4194/TCP   2d18h
kube-dns                                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP         5d18h
```

Tried updating values.yaml to include this:

**Updated values.yaml**

```yaml
prometheus-node-exporter:
  hostRootFsMount: false
```

and this:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheus-node-exporter:
    hostRootFsMount: false
```

However, the issue described, remains, except the log for node-exporter daemonset now gives:

```sh
failed to try resolving symlinks in path "/var/log/pods/default_flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-p5cc8_54c20fc6-c914-4cc6-b441-07b68cda140e/node-exporter/3.log": lstat /var/log/pods/default_flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-p5cc8_54c20fc6-c914-4cc6-b441-07b68cda140e/node-exporter/3.log: no such file or directory
```

**Updated Information From Comment Suggestions**

`kubectl get pod flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-p5cc8`
No args available since node-exporter crashing...

```sh
NAME                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-p5cc8   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          14m
```

The Args from the yaml output of `kubectl describe pod flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-p5cc8` gives:

```yaml
 Args:
      --path.procfs=/host/proc
      --path.sysfs=/host/sys
      --path.rootfs=/host/root
      --web.listen-address=$(HOST_IP):9100
      --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|proc|sys|var/lib/docker/.+|var/lib/kubelet/.+)($|/)
      --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(autofs|binfmt_misc|bpf|cgroup2?|configfs|debugfs|devpts|devtmpfs|fusectl|hugetlbfs|iso9660|mqueue|nsfs|overlay|proc|procfs|pstore|rpc_pipefs|securityfs|selinuxfs|squashfs|sysfs|tracefs)$
```

After updating the values.yaml to include root `kube-prometheus-stack` as suggested in comments of answer allows the prometheus-node-exporter daemonset to start successfully. However, the scrape targets mentioned above are still unavailable....

```yaml
kube-prometheus-stack:
  prometheus-node-exporter:
    hostRootFsMount: false
```

How do I get the node-exporter working and make the associated scrape targets healthy?

Is the node-exporter of the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack#!) helm chart incompatible with Docker Desktop for Mac Kubernetes clusters?

I have raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/1073) at kube-prometheus-stack with log output included for scrape targets for `docker-desktop` and `minikube` clusters.

**Conclusion**
It looks as though the unavailable scrape targets is a problem/bug with kube-prometheus-stack. I searched and found similar issues on their GitHub page: [713](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/713) and [718](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/718). Tried on a minikube cluster with hyperkit vm-driver. On minikube the node-exporter functions out of the box, but the scrape targets issue still occurs. Not sure what a safe solution is?

I may investigate an alternative helm chart dependency for prometheus and grafana...

Comment: I too am on macOS Catalina 10.15.7, albeit on minikube. It's working for me so, I'll try n help. Wrt unhealthy targets like etcd, scheduler etc, can you please share the output of `kubectl get svc -n kube-system`

Comment: Thanks, appreciated :) added log of ```kubectl get svc -n kube-system```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was solved recently. Here is more information: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/467 and here: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/pull/757

Here is the solution (https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/467#issuecomment-802642666):

> [you need to] opt-out the rootfs host mount (preventing the crash). In order to do that you need to specify the following value in values.yaml file:
>
> ```
> prometheus-node-exporter:
>     hostRootFsMount: false
> ```

Comment: It is working for me without needing to specify that. I'm on `minikube version: v1.17.1` (using virtualbox) & `macOS Catalina 10.15.7` & chart v14.4.0. Is it something related to the environment you're on?

Comment: @rock'nrolla yes, but notice OP is using Docker Desktop

Comment: Thanks for replying @matt, appreciated :) Tried that and issue is remaining. I am running tube-prometheus-stack as a dependency in my chart and have added further details to the question of what I tried....

Comment: What is the output of: `kubectl get pod flaskapi-prometheus-node-exporter-7hgnm -oyaml | grep "\- args" -A4` - it will show us whether to `hostRootFsMount` gets propagated to dependencies, and/or install standalone `helm install [RELEASE_NAME] prometheus-community/prometheus-node-exporter --set hostRootFsMount=false` to see if the hostRootFsMount  really does make any difference?

Comment: To propagate `hostRootFsMount` down the depenencies it may require to set `kube-prometheus-stack.prometheus-node-exporter.hostRootFsMount` field. `kube-prometheus-stack` is the name of a top level dependency, `prometheus-node-exporter` is second level dependency.

Comment: Thanks @mat appreciated :) Will try your suggestions and update question with further information when available

Comment: Great!!! Thanks @mat appreciated!!! Used ```kube-prometheus-stack.prometheus-node-exporter.hostRootFsMount``` and node-exporter daemon set is now up and running. Prometheus scrape targets for kube-prometheus-s-kube-scheduler, kube-prometheus-s-kube-proxy, kube-prometheus-s-kube-etcd etc. are  still unavailable. Is that due to the node-exporter ```hostRootFsMount``` being unavailable?

Comment: I belive so. And because of docker desktop you may not be able to make it work at all. If you are determined to make it work it may be best to switch to minikube. @anon_dcs3spp

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help @matt, appreciated. I will accept answer as solving the node-exporter issue. It looks as though the unavailable scrape targets is a problem/bug with kube-prometheus-stack. I searched and found similar issues on their GitHub page: [713](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/713) and [718](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/718). Tried on a minikube cluster with hyperkit vm-driver. On minikube the node-exporter functions out of the box, but the scrape targets issue still occurs.